# Update Parent post type in child theme

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm developing a child theme of a premium template, this comes with a custom post type with the label name of "release" but I'd like to change it to something else, I know that if I go to the functions.php file of the main theme I can change it easily but I'd like to change it from my child theme?
here is the code

```html
<?php
add_action('init', 'kentha_release_register_type');  
if(!function_exists('kentha_release_register_type')){
function kentha_release_register_type() {
 $labelsrelease = array(
  'name' => esc_html__("Release",'kentha'),
  'singular_name' => esc_html__("Release",'kentha'),
  'add_new' => esc_html__("Add new",'kentha'),
  'add_new_item' => esc_html__("Add new release",'kentha'),
  'edit_item' => esc_html__("Edit release",'kentha'),
  'new_item' => esc_html__("New release",'kentha'),
  'all_items' => esc_html__("All releases",'kentha'),
  'view_item' => esc_html__("View release",'kentha'),
  'search_items' => esc_html__("Search release",'kentha'),
  'not_found' => esc_html__("No releases found",'kentha'),
  'not_found_in_trash' => esc_html__("No releases found in trash",'kentha'),
  'menu_name' => esc_html__("Album releases",'kentha')
 );
 $args = array(
  'labels' => $labelsrelease,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui' => true, 
  'show_in_menu' => true, 
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'page',
  'has_archive' => true,
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => 40,
  'page-attributes' => true,
  'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
  'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
  'show_in_menu' => true,
  'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-controls-play',
  'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail','editor', 'page-attributes' )
 ); 
 if (function_exists('ttg_custom_post_type')){
  ttg_custom_post_type( "release" , $args );
 }
 /* ============= create custom taxonomy for the releases ==========================*/
  $labels = array(
  'name' => __( 'Release genres','kentha' ),
  'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Genre','kentha' ),
  'search_items' =>  esc_html__( 'Search by genre','kentha' ),
  'popular_items' => esc_html__( 'Popular genres','kentha' ),
  'all_items' => esc_html__( 'All releases','kentha' ),
  'parent_item' => null,
  'parent_item_colon' => null,
  'edit_item' => esc_html__( 'Edit genre','kentha' ), 
  'update_item' => esc_html__( 'Update genre','kentha' ),
  'add_new_item' => esc_html__( 'Add New genre','kentha' ),
  'new_item_name' => esc_html__( 'New genre Name','kentha' ),
  'separate_items_with_commas' => esc_html__( 'Separate genres with commas','kentha' ),
  'add_or_remove_items' => esc_html__( 'Add or remove genres','kentha' ),
  'choose_from_most_used' => esc_html__( 'Choose from the most used genres','kentha' ),
  'menu_name' => esc_html__( 'Music genres','kentha' ),
 ); 
   $args = array(
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'labels' => $labels,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
  );
   if(function_exists('ttg_custom_taxonomy')){
  ttg_custom_taxonomy('genre','release',$args );
 }
 $fields = array(
  array( // Repeatable & Sortable Text inputs
   'label' => esc_html__( 'Release Tracks','kentha' ), // <label>
   'desc' => esc_html__( 'Add one for each track in the release','kentha' ), // description
   'id' => 'track_repeatable', // field id and name
   'type' => 'repeatable', // type of field
   'sanitizer' => array( // array of sanitizers with matching kets to next array
    'featured' => 'meta_box_santitize_boolean',
    'title' => 'sanitize_text_field',
    'desc' => 'wp_kses_data'
   ),
   
   'repeatable_fields' => array ( // array of fields to be repeated
    'releasetrack_mp3_demo' => array(
     'label' => esc_html__( 'MP3 Demo','kentha' ),
     'desc' => esc_html__( '(Never upload your full quality tracks, someone can steal them)','kentha' ), // description
     'id' => 'releasetrack_mp3_demo',
     'type' => 'file'
    ),
    'releasetrack_track_title' => array(
     'label' => esc_html__( 'Title','kentha' ),
     'id' => 'releasetrack_track_title',
     'type' => 'text'
    ),
    'releasetrack_artist_name' => array(
     'label' => esc_html__( 'Artists','kentha' ),
     'desc' => esc_html__( '(All artists separated bu comma)','kentha' ), // description
     'id' => 'releasetrack_artist_name',
     'type' => 'text'
    ),
    'releasetrack_buy_url' => array(
     'label' => esc_html__( 'Track Buy link','kentha' ),
     'desc' => esc_html__( 'A link to buy the single track','kentha' ), // description
     'id'  => 'releasetrack_buyurl',
     'type'  => 'text'
    ),
    'icon_type' => array(
     'label' => esc_html__( 'Track icon (cart icon is default)','kentha' ),
     'id'  => 'icon_type',
     'type'  => 'select',
     'default' => 'cart',
     'options' => array(
      array('label' => 'cart','value' => 'cart'),
      array('label' => 'download','value' => 'download')
     )
    ),
  
   )
  )
 );


 $fields_links = array(
  array( // Repeatable & Sortable Text inputs
   'label' => esc_html__( 'Custom Buy Links','kentha' ), // <label>
   'desc' => esc_html__( 'Add one for each link to external websites','kentha' ), // description
   'id' => 'track_repeatablebuylinks', // field id and name
   'type' => 'repeatable', // type of field
   'sanitizer' => array( // array of sanitizers with matching kets to next array
    'featured' => 'meta_box_santitize_boolean',
    'title' => 'sanitize_text_field',
    'desc' => 'wp_kses_data'
   ),
   'repeatable_fields' => array ( // array of fields to be repeated
    'custom_buylink_anchor' => array(
     'label' => esc_html__( 'Custom Buy Text','kentha' ),
     'desc' => esc_html__( '(example: Itunes, Beatport, Trackitdown)','kentha' ),
     'id' => 'cbuylink_anchor',
     'type' => 'text'
    ),
    'custom_buylink_url' => array(
     'label' => esc_html__('Custom Buy URL','kentha' ),
     'desc' => esc_html__( '(example: http://...)','kentha' ), // description
     'id' => 'cbuylink_url',
     'type' => 'text'
    )
   )
  )
 );
 $fields_release = array(
  array(
   'label' => esc_html__('Main artist', "kentha"),
   'id' => 'releasetrack_artist',
   'type' => 'post_chosen',
   'posttype' => 'artist'
   ),
  array(
   'label' => esc_html__( 'Label','kentha' ),
   'id'    => 'general_release_details_label',
   'type'  => 'text'
   ),
  array(
   'label' =>esc_html__( 'Release date (YYYY-MM-DD)','kentha' ) ,
   'id'    => 'general_release_details_release_date',
   'type'  => 'date'
   ),
  array(
   'label' => esc_html__( 'Catalog Number','kentha' ),
   'id'    => 'general_release_details_catalognumber',
   'type'  => 'text'
   )
 );
 $details_box = new custom_add_meta_box( 'release_details', 'Release Details', $fields_release, 'release', true );
 $sample_box = new custom_add_meta_box( 'release_tracks', 'Release Tracks', $fields, 'release', true );
 $buylinks_box = new custom_add_meta_box( 'release_buylinkss', 'Custom Buy Links', $fields_links, 'release', true );
}}
```

I need to update in Child Teme the **icon_type** options adding this extra fields

```
array('label' => 'spotify','value' => 'spotify')
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: your code is out of context. need theme name, file name, the line of code, which you provided. and it'll be great, if you'll provide the full function with it's handlers, hooks of the code

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a piece of code. Just updated the code above

Comment: is the function a part of some php class?

Comment: if not, just copy-paste the code provided into your child theme `functions.php` file with changes you want. may throw 500error, so be sure you have access to file from filemanager/ftp.

Comment: No!! This is release-type.php

Comment: I tried but it doesn’t work

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: I did in the past few days but nothing appeared. I re-did now, i switch to the parent theme then to the child and "voilà" it works! Thanks